# lldb error in swift

Tags: xcode, swift, lldb

So I am trying to follow standford's swift lecture series.. However, when I am trying to play the following code, it get 'lldb' error. Any help will be appreciated.. Many thanks

```
import UIKit
class ViewController: UIViewController {


@IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel!

var userIsIntheMiddleOfTyping = false

@IBAction func touchDigit(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let digit = sender.currentTitle!

    if userIsIntheMiddleOfTyping {
        let textCurrentInDisplay = display.text!
        display.text = textCurrentInDisplay + digit
    } else {
        display.text = digit
    }
    userIsIntheMiddleOfTyping = true
  }
}
```

It is to note that when the debugger opens the following line of code is highlighted,

```
    let digit = sender.currentTitle!
```

Comment: Whats the error that the compiler is showing? Is it finding nil? the ! at the end of the line means that you are force unwrapping an optional value, that might be nil at the time.

Comment: Is your `@IBOutlet` connected?

Comment: Can you show the console error info?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line of code below, you are forcing unwrapping of optional value.

```
let digit = sender.currentTitle!
```

The compiler is trying to tell you that.

How to solve the problem?

1. Make sure that the all the values are connected and are not `nil`. In this specific case, the `@IBOutlet weak var display: UILabel!` outlet might not be connected.
2. If you are not sure that if the value is `nil` or not, use conditional statements and handle the `nil` case. For example:

   ```
   if let digit = sender.currentTitle {
     print("Great, its working")
   } else {
     print("error: currentTitle is nil")
   }
   ```